# Prime ideals in coordinate rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Is there a way to characterise prime ideals in affine coordinate rings (i.e. quotients of polynomial rings). To be more specific, how can I say if principal ideals in such rings are prime or not in an elementary way?

Comment: There are certainly tests for whether ideals are prime.  You can find some on page 209 of *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms* by Cox, Little and O'Shea.  It's certainly implemented in various computer algebra systems (such as Macaulay2).

Comment: Or rather, in that book you can find some discussion of history and references.

Comment: If you know your ring is a UFD, then your question reduces to checking if the generator of your principal ideal is irreducible.  Also note that in a UFD every prime ideal of height 1 is principal.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $S=R[X_1,...,X_n]$.

If a principal prime ideal in the coordinate ring $A$ is represented by $f \in S$, a necessary condition is that $f$ is irreducible.

In order to generalize, let $\kappa: S \to A$ be an epimorphism. An ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ from $A$ is prime iff $P := \kappa^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ is prime in $S$. This reduces the problem to determing the prime ideals in $S$. Such a characterization is given in a paper [(link)](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-01/S0002-9939-97-03663-0/S0002-9939-97-03663-0.pdf) of Ferrero dated from 1997:

First he generalizes the notion of irreducibility (cf. Def. 2.4, 1.7), called "complete irreducibility". For an prime ideal $Q$ in $R$ and a sequence of polynomials $f_i \in R[X_1,...,X_i]$, $1 \le i \le n$, he defines an ideal $[Q,f_1,...,f_n]$ (that is simply either $(f_1,...,f_n)$ or $S$ if $R$ is a field). Then

> An ideal $P$ in $S$ with $P \cap R = Q$ is prime iff there are completely irreducible polynomials $f_i \in R[X_1,...,X_i]$ such that $P=[Q,f_1,...,f_n]$.

Remarks: 1) A description of the primes in $S$ that takes the height into account can be found in Eisenbud: Commutative Algebra, Exercise 13.6.

2) If the coordinate ring is known to be Cohen-Macaulay, Serre's criterion may be of interest (cf. Eisenbud, Theorem 18.15).

3) The OP is primarily interested in principal ideals in $A$. By writing $A=S/I$ with $I= (g_1,...,g_{k-1})$ and $\mathfrak{p} = (\bar{g}_k)$, one finds $P = \kappa^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) = (g_1,...,g_k)$. Thus, for general $I$, I don't think that restriction to principal ideals actually simplifies the problem.